# How many ways (methods) there are to solve Cauchy-Euler equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have seen at least three different ways to solve it. The first, by trial solution. The second, using a change of variable. The third, by Power series... Oh! And Frobenius too.... So I was wondering, should I just use the easiest?. For example, using trial solution instead of Frobenius. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use whatever you are comfortable with.  You can just write down the solution by inspection if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "trial solution" you mean establishing the characteristic polynomial and getting the basis solutions from it, then that is the same as the Frobenius (and) power series method. As there the indicial condition for the leading power is the same as the characteristic polynomial, with the same consequences.

So in fact you only have 2 really different methods.